# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'cacheKeyOptions' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-dom, babel-jest

As part of nodejs 18 upgrade, the following versions were upgraded.

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2"
"jest": "29.7.0",
"jest-cli": "29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "29.7.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-stage-2": "7.0.0",
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
"babel-loader": "8.2.2",
"@babel/core": "7.0.0",
```

In the babel config file, presets also were updated:

```
presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-stage-2', '@babel/env'],
```

After running npm run test, I am getting the following error:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'cacheKeyOptions' as it is undefined.
>
>   at Object.getCacheKey (node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js:217:14)
> ```

Other forums mentioned to use the babel-jest version 26.6.3 but it doesn't help.

Comment: Use the same version of jest as babel-jest. Try set the version of `babel-jest` to `29.7.0`. You may need to update additionally other versions. See this [peerDependencies here](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/v29.7.0/packages/babel-jest/package.json#L4)

Comment: babel-jest version 29.7.0 is giving issue on presets and plugins. Is there anything I need to add in the plugins and presets apart from what I have mentioned. @OluwafemiSule

Comment: Test suite failed to run due to Unknown option: .canInstrument. 

@OluwafemiSule

Comment: I don't think I have the complete information to reproduce the observed error.
Can you provide a minimal project that reproduces it?